# Grid Column Definition - Use of Asterisks

Tags: wpf

I recently saw some XAML code that looked as follows:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Does this mean that the first and third columns will each consume 2/9 of the available space and the second column will consume 5/9?

Comment: [Manual?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is just a ratio of the total.